# Subdomain to heroku subdomain

Tags: heroku, dns, subdomain, cname

I have a heroku app, lets call it `showering-wind-33`. I purchased a top level domain, let's call it `example.com`, and correctly configured my domain to render content on heroku by adding a CNAME pointing to `showering-wind-33.herokuapp.com`. So when I visit `example.com` it renders the content from `showering-wind-33.herokuapp.com`.

I have another domain `foo.com` and I want `store.foo.com` to point to a the content in `store_for_foo.example.com`, and I'm having problems doing this.

I tried:
1. Adding a CNAME record in my DNS to point `store.foo.com` to `store_for_foo.example.com`
2. Adding `store.foo.com` to "Domains" under Settings in my heroku app.

But the result is that `store.foo.com` ends up pointing to `example.com` but not `store_for_foo.example.com`

What am I doing incorrectly? Any help would be appreciated - thanks! How can I get the content of `store.foo.com` to show `store_for_foo.example.com`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't be done with pure DNS, but there are some alternatives:

1. Use example.com/store, and have store.foo.com URL redirect to that.
2. Use some sort of middleware to pipe those requests on that domain only.
3. Remind your husband that he has written a book containing a section on DNS and he should know this ;).